# Can an Ace be low in a straight?

Tags: texas-hold-em, reading-hands

I was under the impression that, in Texas Holdem, "Aces are always high". However, I have been playing online and I noticed that aces are used in a low straight (A, 2, 3, 4, 5). Was I mistaken that "Aces are always high", or is the online app that I have been using in error by using aces as low card in a straight?

Comment: I guess one of the intentions of all the Stack Exchange sites *is* to be where one looks things up, as the network is a trusted source, the question ranks highly in SEO, and the answer will be peer-reviewed by a educated community?

Comment: Do not understand ace to nine straight? Please explain.

Comment: @C.Fetner it sounds like you're playing shortdeck poker.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aces may indeed be used as low in a straight in holdem.  A2345 is the lowest possible straight, also sometimes called a "wheel." In any other context, aces will be ranked higher than other cards.

Comment: Also straight flushes: A2345 suited beats quads, but loses to 23456 suited. All poker games using traditional high hands recognize the wheel as a straight, except "Deuce to Seven" (aka "Kansas City") lowball. In 2-to-7, a wheel is just A-5-4-3-2 high, thus beating any other A-high, but losing to K-high.

Comment: Note that `23456` is a better straight than `A2345` whose value compared to other straights is ranked by the `5` and not the `A`.

Comment: @Paulpro Hence my wording describing A2345 as the "lowest possible straight."

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Yea, your answer is good. The note wasn't intended for you. I was just providing additional clarification, for the OP or any other reader, by giving an example comparing it to the next lowest straight.

Comment: I once played pai-gow poker, A pit game where your playing against the house, I had a king high straight, the dealer had a wheel, they said the wheel won because it was ace high. I just left and never played the game again. In home games and casino table games you may want clarify.

Comment: For Pai Gow Poker as played in Nevada, the casino was correct: wheel beats a K-high straight, but loses to Broadway. California casinos play the wheel low, as in normal poker.